# Google Chrome developer tools start very slowly

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, chromium, developer-tools

I use Chrome v.49.0.2623.87 m. and recently the developer tools work very slowly. My OS is Windows 10.

Steps:

- I press F12 and the empty window(like [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zmii1xk0sk2div/chrome-dev-tools-1.png?dl=0)) appears
- then after ~ 10 seconds appears something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf60i5onag9iamw/chrome-dev-tools-2.png?dl=0). But tabs("Elements", "Console", "Sources" etc.) don't work.
- and after ~ 10 seconds the dev tools start work. There is the message - "SW registered" in the console.

So, total time of the dev tools loading is about 20 seconds.

I've already removed all extensions and reinstalled the browser. But the problem is still here.

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Same problem, on win 7.
It seems also all my team is suffering from this issue, I think some bug in recent release

Comment: BTW: I've reported the issue like described here - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still reproduced in the newest version -  49.0.2623.108 m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this issue was fixed in the latest Google Chrome version. I've updated the browser to v.53.0.2785.143 and it works fine.